Watching for /sys/class/net file changes using systemd
I'm trying to get a systemd service to restart when some ethernet cable gets plugged in, by monitoring changes to the /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier_up_count system file.
I tried creating a systemd path service:
[Path]
PathModified=/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier_up_count
Unit=restart-other-service.service

but, while I can see that the carrier_up_count indeed changes when I plug the cable in, this path service never gets triggered.
I assume this happens because systemd path services actually monitors when files are open and closed for writing, and the /sys/ files are always open (I can see that the last modified timestamp of the file doesn't change even though the contents of the file does).
I also tried using a systemd socket service with ListenSpecial=/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier_up_count, but the service failed:
Got unexpected poll event (0x9) on socket.
Failed with result 'resources'.

Is there a way to get systemd to monitor changes on the files in /sys/ ? I guess I could just create a cronjob that reads the target file periodically but it feels like there should be a better way.

No, file system monitoring is a kernel function, and systemd just uses this function.
The sysfs file system is a mapping of kernel objects to file names, and does not support inotify.
The best way to monitor interface up/down events is through netlink (the ip mon command shows what events are available there), but the systemd configuration language does not provide a keyword for that.
If the service in question is dependent on having a network connection, it may be possible to declare a dependency on that, but I'm not sure the teardown semantics of the component stack are well defined, that is a glaring hole in the specification.
